# CSS background property seemingly does nothing for me

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a simple background image onto a page I'm working on and I can't seem to get the CSS to work for it.

```
html, body {
  background: url("../assets/images/bgart.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This does nothing, no image. I've tried every possible url(path) and so many other things, but I'm having to resort to:

```
body background="assets/images/bgart.jpg">
```

in the main .html file for it to come up somewhat correctly. I would like it to be applied to the html tag to cover all the space, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the file path correct in `background: url("../assets/images/bgart.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;` ?

Comment: Have you linked html and css file?

Comment: What is your folder structure? Where is CSS file located?  http://jsfiddle.net/nexae5ce/ Your path is wrong, probably.... CSS will work.

Comment: @DavidLi I've tried every possible path I can think of, and I'm just trying to get it to work with a barebones html and css file.

and @ nevermind root has index.html and assets folder, assets has main.css and images folder, images has bgart.jpg

Comment: Try `/assets/images/bgart.jpg`. This starts you at the root of your project.

Comment: @DavidLi That did not work.

Comment: On your console it should say something like `FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE: ` followed by the path it is currently looking at. Take a look at that and adjust your path accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm just using Komodo Edit to edit the html and css and loading it directly into chrome, how do I check a console for this information?

Comment: So, I can load directly from a url an image perfectly fine, but getting something local is giving me trouble. I've tried every path I can think of and still nothing.

Comment: Press F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+C and click the tab Console. If you cannot see it, click the arrows, then click console

Comment: uhhhh... I have no idea what the heck I did, but the path I started this question with works now??????? Why would something like that happen?

also what does it mean when things are crossed out in the console view? https://puu.sh/kG1Dp/7177905c97.png

Comment: The ones that browser doesn't use are crossed out. So your browser doesn't need the prefixed versions. If your style sheet is in the `assets` folder, your path could just be `url("images/bgart.jpg")`.

Comment: Did you try background-image: url("../assets/images/bgart.jpg"); too?

Answer (score 0):

If your folders structure is like this:

```
assets
  -- css
  -- js
  -- images
index.html
```

Then you are refering the in the wrong path. Supposing that your `style.css` or whatever the style file is called is inside the css folder, the correct path should be like this:

```
html, body {
  background: url("../images/bgart.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This error IMO at least is simple to resolve if you use the Developer Tools that almost every major browser has already integrated, or if you use Mozilla Firefox (like you should use lol), you can just try Firebug Inspector it has all its needed to debug your problems.

Answer (score 0):

CSS for background image is fine, but the URL is probably not. To see if CSS is working you can use image from web

```
html, body {
    background: url("https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AThe_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

True path to the image is from where the CSS is. Let's say you keep your folders structured like

```
/website
--- index.html
--- /css
--- --- style.css
--- /images
--- --- background.jpg
```

In this structure you would have style.css linked inside index.html, but your path to background.jpg would be ("./images/background.jpg"), where the dot takes you to one directory back.

If you have CSS inside index.html, the path would be only ("images/background.jpg"), because you already start in root directory.